# How to setup custom id-field in DB4O

Tags: db4o

I've read the documentation and samples multiple times and can't find out how to do this.,

I'm trying to wire up DB4O to use my own custom Id field. based on the documentation you can define your own IDs but as far as I can tell they won't replace Db4o's internal IDs, As in it won't actually use those Ids to identify the objects.

Basically all the examples do are tell Db4o to generate some sort of unique id and index it, I don't see anywhere on how to tell it that this is the ID that you should use.

Is it possible to have our own IDs on our model replace the internal IDs used to keep track of the relationships?

*we need to have our own Ids since our system relies heavily on REST.*

Answer (score 0):

There no direct support for this. You need to create your own mechanism.

- Simplest way: Use Guid on .NET. Or use a UUID in Java. In Java: Add [UUID-Support](http://community.versant.com/documentation/reference/db4o-8.1/java/reference/Content/advanced_topics/type_handling/uuid_support.htm?SearchType=Stem&Highlight=UUIDs%7CUUID%7Cuuids%7Cuuid): `configuration.common().add(new UuidSupport());`
- Use callback to create [new id's](http://community.versant.com/documentation/reference/db4o-8.1/java/reference/Content/platform_specific_issues/disconnected_objects/example_id_generator.htm). Doesn't not work in TCP client/server.

See also this [page](http://community.versant.com/documentation/reference/db4o-8.1/java/reference/Content/platform_specific_issues/disconnected_objects/comparison_of_ids.htm).

Side note: You build a REST app. How many request does it need to handle? db4o is internally inherently single threaded. It can only handle a very limited load.